# WhoId (Contact) on Task is not getting assigned

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, activities, before-trigger

I have a trigger on Task Record. i.e. for before insert the code will update the WhatId and WhoId values if the task is created on specific object(Outbound_Fax__c in this case). WhatId(Case Record Id) is populated as expected. But, WhoId(Contact Record Id) is not getting assigned, even though I can see the value in debug logs. Please suggest me if I am doing anything wrong in assigning WhoId.

**Debug Log**

[image: WhoId=003...]

**Detail View**

[image: Blank Name]

**Code**

```
public with sharing class MSH_TaskTriggerHandler {

    public static void beforeInsert(List<Task> newTasks) {
    Map<Id, Task> outboundFaxTasks = new Map<Id, Task>();
    String objectName;
        for(Task t: newTasks) {
      if(t.WhatId != null) {
        // Retrieve the object name based on record Id
        objectName = MSH_SchemaGlobalDescribe.findObjectNameFromRecordIdPrefix(t.WhatId);
        if(objectName != null
           && objectName.equalsIgnoreCase('Outbound_Fax__c')) {
          outboundFaxTasks.put(t.Id, t);
        }
      }
    }
    if(!outboundFaxTasks.isEmpty()) {
      reParentingOutboundFaxActivity(newTasks, outboundFaxTasks);
    }
    }
    public static void reParentingOutboundFaxActivity(List<Task> newTasks, Map<Id, Task> outboundfaxActivityList) {

    Map<Id, Id> caseByOutboundFax = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Map<Id, Outbound_Fax__c> outboundFaxById = new Map<Id, Outbound_Fax__c>();

    Set<Id> outboundFaxIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Task t: outboundfaxActivityList.values()) {
      if(t.WhatId != null) {
        // Adding all the outbound Fax record Id's
        outboundFaxIds.add(t.WhatId);
      }
    }
    if(!outboundFaxIds.isEmpty()) {
      for(Outbound_Fax__c obf: [SELECT Id,
                                       Case__c,
                                       Subject__c,
                                       Contact__c
                                FROM Outbound_Fax__c
                                WHERE Id IN: outboundFaxIds]) {
        if(obf.Case__c != null) {
          caseByOutboundFax.put(obf.Id, obf.Case__c);
          outboundFaxById.put(obf.Id, obf);
        }
      }

      if(!caseByOutboundFax.isEmpty()
         && !outboundFaxById.isEmpty()) {
        for(Task t: newTasks) {
          if(outboundfaxActivityList.containsKey(t.Id)) {
            Id oldWhatId = t.WhatId; // Store the Old value of WhatId
            if(caseByOutboundFax.containsKey(oldWhatId)
               && caseByOutboundFax.get(oldWhatId) != null
               && outboundFaxById.containsKey(oldWhatId)
               && outboundFaxById.get(oldWhatId) != null
               && oldWhatId != null) {
              t.WhatId = caseByOutboundFax.get(oldWhatId); // Assign the WhatId with Case value
              t.Subject = outboundFaxById.get(oldWhatId).Subject__c;
              t.Type = 'Outbound';
              t.Sub_Type__c = 'Fax';
              t.WhoId = outboundFaxById.get(oldWhatId).Contact__c;
              System.debug('About to be Updated Task===='+t);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other `Triggers`/`Workflow Rules`/`Flows` (e.g. `Process Builder`) that might conflict with this field update?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for the reply. I have just now come across a trigger on Task for Before insert/ Update. But there isn't any assignment of whoId in that. Will that be a reason for why only WhoId is not getting updated? I mean all others were getting assigned except that field.

Comment: You need to look for something else that sets that field. A trigger that doesn't set it wouldn't be relevant. Keep looking.

Comment: Would suggest you to create an afterInsert trigger, query the task with WhoId field and check if it's empty. If it is - the problem's in other triggers. If it isnt' - the problem's in WF/Flow/ProcessBuilder. Also I would set maximum debug level to WF and Apex Code and read through debug logs.